# How to query mongodb without knowing dynamic field type in Java?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I want to create some APIs, which let user pass in just strings for types like number, boolean. And automatically convert them before querying mongodb. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible for MongoDB. You could write your own utility to convert string in mongo specific query or you could use some open source utilities like [enter link description here](https://github.com/vincentrussell/sql-to-mongo-db-query-converter).

Eventually, MongoDB accepts JSON string to execute the same client does also convert each query in the same JSON format. MongoDB clients or MongoDB doesn't need any predefined mapping or POJO.

This utility will convert string as shown below -

User string -

"select * from users where firstName='Vijay' AND lastName='Rajput'"

Then this utility will convert it into -

db.users.find({$and: [{firstName: 'Vijay'}, {lastName: 'Rajput'}]})